# Call Multiple Files on Express - EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

i am using express 4 - ejs combination for my web app, and i am wondering how can i render multiple files depend on the route / url that being called.

Let's say that i have `header.ejs` that i want to render on every page, and header.ejs code is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header-area">Header IS Gonna Be Here</div>
  <div class="content-area">Content Area Gonna Be Different on Every Page Depend on the Router</div>
</div>
```

My existing method in calling the header.ejs file is `using res.render()` but i can't figure it out to render multiple file at the same time. Thank you for your answer, if you feel that my question has been asked already, can you give me the link then i will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept is called templating your layout, basically create the partials like header footer that remain static. on res.render() you will render the view with the data you need and add to that the header and footers :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
  res.render('index',{user:"John Smith"}) 
// pass main ejs file name, pass any data variables 
});
```

To render file named index.ejs, combine with other ejs files using include statement. Do make sure index.ejs is in the views directory as you have set initially

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
< html lang="en">
  < head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
  </ head>
  < body class="container">
    < header>
      <% include ../partials/header %>
    </ header>
    < main>
      < div class="jumbotron">
        < h1> This is great </ h1>
        < p> Welcome to templating using EJS </ p>
        < p> welcome <%= user%>;< /p>
      </ div>
    </ main>
    < footer>
      <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </ footer>
  </ body>
</ html>
```

[Check for tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application)

Comment: and how to differentiate which file to include on different route ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the include method like mine:

```
<%- include('includes/header') %>
```

And for this you need to create a folder `header.ejs`, and move all your code there, and you need to use the include connection in all your ejs files.

Comment: The answer is incorrect, "header.ejs" is a file not a folder. Can you please edit and clarify what you mean?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).